# samsung gear app communication

Tags: android, communication, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am planning to develop an app for the gear (s) and a samsung galaxy mobile (note 3). 
I want the user to be able to choose from a list (same like in the gear app of samsung) of all installed apps. The notifications of the selected apps shall get sent to the gear and the notifications of the apps that are not selected in the list shall get sent to another bluetooth device.

Since I know that the communication of the samsung gear is very weird, I wanted to ask if it is possible  for my app to communicate with the gear S to rely the notifications to the gear.

Also, since the note 3 runs android and the gear S runs tizen, how does the communication have to look? Do I send my notifications as JSONs to the gear, or how can the gear know that it shall display the notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Android notifications are passed to the Gear using the method you describe.

There is a deeper mechanism that you can use called [Rich Notifications](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#rich-notification). Part of the solution runs on Android and you can write JavaScript web apps to respond to the messages on Tizen. JSON is not necessary for Rich Notification. If you want to set up a two-way communication link between watch and phone, use the [Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#accessory).

There are sample apps in the SDKs showing how the communication occurs on both sides.