# How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?

Tags: android, integration, tizen, samsung-gear, samsung-gear-fit

I want to integrate Samsung Gear device for steps in my application, also jawbone Steps and misfit Steps. I've looked at several things, like the [Samsung Gear Site](http://developer.samsung.com/gear), but found nothing that works for me.

Comment: Can you plean explain what do you mean by integreting Samsung Gear steps?

Comment: do you know fitbit, jawbone and misfit device?

Comment: i want to integrate samsung gear device for steps integration.

Comment: this might be a good starting point? http://developer.samsung.com/gear

Comment: i was tried but nothing on samsung developer site for steps integration. @Flummox

Comment: There is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877223/samsung-gear-app-communication does that help?

Comment: I don't know for Gear or jawbone but Fitbit provide a REST API to get the values send to their servers. I don't know if there is a ContentProvider to get those from the app (can't sync without internet so I doubt this would really help). I doubt you can read the values directly in bluetooth since this should be secure (SHOULD ;) ).

Comment: i want to integrate samsung gear steps integration

Comment: jawbone, misfit and fitbit i have alrady done

Comment: You can read gear steps using Samsung Digital Health SDK. For that, you have to install S Health app in your phone.  For more details about Digital Health SDK , check the link: [link] (http://developer.samsung.com/health)  .  You will find details in the  programming guide attached with this site. Also there is a sample code for steps count in this site. Check the following link to know details about step count. [link] (http://img-developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/health/index.html)

Comment: Samsung Digital Health is not Providing REST API for steps cout like FITBIT.

Comment: i have tried but i don't find anything about REST API for steps count down

Comment: http://marctan.com/blog/2014/07/08/reading-heart-rate-data-from-samsung-gear-live/

Comment: its a heart rate data i need calories intake, calories burn and steps data. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @RiyazParasara Then you should customise on it

Comment: how can i customize please demonstrate me
i can't find HEART SENSOR in Android Mobile Application SDK .

Comment: Give me a code for my application steps integration with samsung gear device.

Comment: that is Heart Rate demo please read first of all and then put it. @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: i m trying whole day but its not worth full. @IntelliJAmiya

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For connection and data transfer between mobile android device and Samsung Gear device , [Accessory Protocol](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web-companion/use-sap) is defined. So, the option available here is using [Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory) for Android mobile and Tizen wearable.

Tizen provides [HumanActivityMonitor](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor) for 3rd party developers to retrieve Pedometer step count data.

I have developed a **sample app in Tizen platform** for reading pedometer step count data in gear and send the data to Consumer Android mobile app while the mobile and wearable is connected through **Samsung Gear Manager**. Its just a customization over the sample apps available on the sites reffered.

I am sharing the **code of the tizen web app along with the installer**(.wgt) file. If you are not interested in tizen development right now, you may install the app directly to the Samsung gear using the wgt file.

I am also sharing the **code of the android app along with the installer**(.apk) file. You may try a sample transmission between the devices and do your code on android platform as necessary. I have tested the apps on my devices and they are working good, though some data inconsistency occurs.

Zip file link:

Android consumer app (apk)

Android consumer app (code)

Tizen provider app (wgt)

Tizen provider app (code)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6KEP_6UcxrATllCWTlmeUh1M28/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[Human activity monitor API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/wearable/tizen/humanactivitymonitor.html)

[Human Activity Monitor Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor)

[Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory)

Please read the Accessory guide and HumanActivityMonitor guide for details implementation, you would find simple explanation there.

Comment: The drive link is dead, but you can find the sample code up on the official Samsung developer page: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-tizen/samples/companion/hello-web.html