# Sending Gear 2 accelerometer data to phone or computer

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm able to see the accelerometer data on my gear 2 using what I've found [here](http://denvycom.com/blog/accelerometer-data-in-javascript-in-your-gear-2/) and now I'm trying to send that data to my phone or computer for real time analysis. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189733/syncing-accelerometer-data-of-android-wear-to-phone-or-computer)  discusses how to send the data with android wear but I can't find any documentation to send the data from a tizen OS.

Comment: Adding some code samples here with help as to what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Samsung Accessory SDK. Accessory SDK allows you to connect accessory devices to Android mobile devices. With Accessory SDK, you can connect bi-directionally from Tizen wearable to Android mobile and vice versa.

Please go through the Samples provided with the SDK download package. You can check out lots of samples with Tizen Data Provider App & Android Data Consumer apps and vise versa. You may also go through the programming guide and API references.

[Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory)

You may also find some idea from this post slightly similar to your query :
[How to integrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913)

In the Case of passing data to Computer you have to develop an application (on any platform you prefer) , Then use the Bluetooth communication protocol to communicate with the Gear.

Comment: Ok I have the application running on the watch. Where could I find the information for setting up the bluetooth protocol ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Gear2 or GearS2 ?

I can explain for both anyway.

For G2 use Samsung Accessory Protocol (SAP) and you need android as receiver then you can forward event to your system, there is maybe some other hackish solution but you need IP anyway because G2 is BT only.

See "developer resources" at:

https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Wearable

Watch this in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UHGfl5VPGQc&t=8s&list=PLW_oRrdNdnFmbSu73bhbfohAJ7El82FN4&index=19

For GearS2 or GearS3. iotivity is what you need check:

http://www.slideshare.net/SamsungOSG/iotivity-on-tizen-how-to

Feel free to form wearable branches from:

https://github.com/tizenteam/iotivity-example

Note that GearS has wifi so you could use iotivity too ...

More info at:

https://wiki.iotivity.org/tizen

Comment: I am using the Gear 2 . Would you happen to have any sample code? I'm relatively new to mobile app development.