# Open link on wearable in browser on the phone

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I have asked this question on  the Samsung developer forum but didn't get any response so I try my luck here. I have noted that the Flipboad app (that I run on my Gear S3) can open a link in the android phones web browser when I click on a button. I would like to add this feature to an app that I develop. I have search on how to do this but I could not find anything. Does anyone have a sample code that shows how to do this? My app is a Web app but am also interested of this function for Native code.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can develop the functionality you want to using Accessory SDK. There are Programming guides and sample codes (Both Android & Tizen end) available here.

[Accessory SDk](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory)

Samsung Developers > Galaxy > SDK > Accessory

You can get some hint from this post here, where I passed data from Gear to android.

[How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913)

I think you can easily write code on android to launch app(browser) with data(url). All you have to do is to pass data(url) from tizen.

Comment: And that's why you don't just post links as an answer. They are dead.