# How to get raw data(Heart Rate etc) from samsung gear s3 in Android

Tags: android, tizen, raw-data, samsung-gear

I want to buy Samsung Gear S3 for development.
I want to use raw data that Gear S3 has.
I searched many sites, but I couldn't find how to get raw data from Gear S3 in Android using BLE. Any help please?

Comment: Have you tried checking the S3 gear [developer documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/gear)?

Comment: Thx.  I see this. https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors?langredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic Seems vast. I haven't seen some example code to fetch data directly from hardware layer sensor of another device of another platform. I know You can transfer the data in application layer using common BLE protocol.  In Tizen, you can chose your suitable platform Native (C/C++) or Web (js/HTML/CSS)

You can start from checking out the  [Tizen Native Sensor Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors), It discusses how to fetch sensor data from wearable device.

To get example on establishing Bluetooth LE connection with device, [Tizen Native BLE guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/connectivity-and-wireless/bluetooth#le_scan) would be helpful I guess. [Android Bluetooth LE Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) covers sample for android part.

I passed sensor data from tizen wearable device to android, and that was using Samsung Accessory SDK. You can see the response here.

[How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913)

Useful links I would consider:

[Tizen Web Sensor guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors/device-sensors)

[Tizen Web Human Activity Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor)

[Tizen Sensor API for wearable Native](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__MODULE.html)

[Tizen Web Bluetooth API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/bluetooth.html)

Comment: Thank you for comment. I used Native app using tizen studio. Thank you so much!