# Vibrate gear device(Tizen OS) through actions of android application

Tags: android, tizen

I have created an android application for face recognition and now I want to make a feature so that I can vibrate my gear s2 device whenever new face is detected.

Can you please let me know how we can communicate with Tizen and android os. Also, how we can send the alert or how we can vibrate the gear device connected to android devices.

I am very new to Tizen OS development so please help on this.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Tizen-Android Communication**:

There is a Protocol called [Samsung Accessory Protocol](http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/creating-your-first-app/web-companion/use-sap) to communicate and data transfer between Samsung Gear device and Android Smart phone. An SDK is provided to develop these kind of application called [Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory).
Some sample apps are given with the SDK. You can use those to develop your app.

I will suggest you to follow this answer [How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913) to get idea the communication between Tizen Gear and Android phone.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

**Vibration in Tizen**:

Tizen provides [Vibration](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/device/vibration) in web app.

```
function singleVibration() {
     /* Vibrate for 2 seconds */
     navigator.vibrate(2000);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Will try to implement it and update it here with results.