# Connecting Samsung Gear with Android via BLE, Rest API

Tags: android, sdk, tizen, google-health

I am developing an application,that should communicate with **Samsung Gear** watch/wear to get all activity details ( step,calories and more ) from android. I have come up with **Accessible SDK**.

Someone help on this find the concrete example or solution, should be appreciated.

I referred this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529913 
But in this example, they provider a (wearable app ) and consumer app ( android app).
Is there any solution without provider app.

Comment: Without provided app, who will provide you the data? Rest Server?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read ( step,calories and more ) from your Tizen
wearable device you need a Tizen app on your Tizen device to read/extract those values.

Once you've got these sensor values make communication between those apps(Tizen, Android) like using Rest API or BLE.

Comment: Thanks for your response . I still need few calrification
1) Does Tizen wearable application provide data to any android device or only Samsung android device ?
2) How to get these data ? From any library ( Accessible SDK ) or native BLE ?

Comment: Rest API - Any device that has internet connectivity (pc, mobile).
Native Code for Bluetooth implementation - Any device that bluetooth connectivity (pc, mobile).
Accessory SDK - Any Android/iOS Device connected with gear via gear manager (Complete Example:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40529913).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to get the activity info from Gear watch without a wearable app. The Samsung Health App in Android sync the health data using it's corresponding Samsung Health app in the wearable device.

With a wearable app you can use Tizen Health API for retrieving the health activity information from the Gear device. You can use communicate it with your Android app using the methods mentioned above.

You can also research into Samsung Health SDK if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for your response, May I use the Samsung Health SDK, to fetch all the data like ( steps , sleep and etc..) without wearable app from any samsung wearable (watch, fit)