# How to pass/get Health rate data from Samsung S3 Gear to a Mobile

Tags: android, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I have created a sample **Tizen** native Health App for **Samsung S3 Gear** and installed in Gear device and its working.

How can I get the Data from the Gear to Mobile, What should I do next ?

Below is the sample native app link which I tested.
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

You can also send the data directly to the cloud from the Samsung wearable Gear Sport using this code:

```
function sendData() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            console.log('done');
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                alert("data send successfully!");
            } else {
                alert("failed to send data!");
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("POST", API_URL);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var data = {
        "key" : "foo",
        "value": "bar",
        "timestamp": 123
    };

    xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

and then you can call `sendData()` function like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var API_URL = "https://foobar.foo/endpoint"
    sendData();
}
```

Comment: Can you share some sample code for this. I am using Samsung S3 Gear Frontier

Answer (score 0):

I've shared a solution with sample application in this relevant post. Please Check it out for details:

[How to integrate Samsung Gear Steps in android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233692/how-to-integrate-samsung-gear-steps-in-android-application/40529913#40529913)

You have to use [Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/accessory). This Sample Above consists of Tizen Web Application, In your case you would need Native. You would find Native Sample/Template on Accessory SDK Package.

Comment: Thanks a lot  and really appreciate for your answer. I will try the below Tizen native sample application and let you know.

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/community/tip-tech/accessing-heart-rate-monitor-hrm-sensor-data-native-applications?langredirect=1